# How to display an icon when you add a site to favorites in web?

Tags: html, web

When I open web page from Iphone or Ipad I see icon of web site. How I can do it for my web site?

Comment: Do you want a favicon? o_O i do not know what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of images you can include (splash, home screen, etc.) listed in Apple's documentation. The one you're talking about is the `apple-touch-icon`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="touch-icon-ipad.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="touch-icon-iphone-retina.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">
```

Comment: This is just the right answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by adding a 'favicon'. Favicons can be added with the code below:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="**LINK TO YOUR PICTURE LOCATION**"
```

Favicons often are 16x16 or 32x32 size PNG images.

You can generate favicons at sites like http://www.favicon-generator.org

Comment: You can use more than PNG files http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Sorry, thank you. Edited to state "often are" instead of "must be"